# Calling a Bootstrap popup from grails controller

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails

I need to display an error message popup as shown in the following [link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) . It should appear on top of the page for a few seconds and then fade away.

```
if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {

    // THE ERROR POPUP SHOULD BE CALLED FROM HERE

    return
}else  {
   ...
}
```

Where should I place the code in my HTML and how should I call it from GRAILS controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any view that displays data from a controller you should place this information into your model. I would recommend you settle on a standard element in your model to make this easier to implement for your entire project (which I assume is where you are headed).

So For example, in your controller(s):

```
def model = [:]
model['userInstance'] = userInstance
...
if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
    // set/lookup the error message
    model['errorMessage'] = message(code: 'some.error.message.you.lookup')
    // render the view
    render(view: 'theviewname', model: model)

    return
}else  {
   ...
}
```

Then you can display this in your view (or layout):

```
<g:if test="${errorMessage}">
  <div class="class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">${errorMessage}</div>
</g:if>
```

I will leave the making it fade away (sprinkle of jquery) out of the picture since the concept here is the most important part.

Hope this helps, and welcome to Grails!

Comment: I actually want it to appear when the user successfully logins. and i don't have a authController.groovy file to edit the code. How can i sort it ?

Comment: It would be best to make a new question, showing a controller which populates the model, the main.gsp layout you are using, and the view which uses the layout. That way we can all help, and have the information needed to do so.