# Showing login success message popup

Tags: grails

Once the user successfully logins to the system, I want to display a success message. Therefore I'm thinking to do it as shown in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711005/calling-a-bootstrap-popup-from-grails-conroller/24711853#24711853) post.

However, I'm not able to find the controller of the `auth.groovy` file, therefore it's not possible to place the code as shown in the above mentioned SO post.

How can I solve it?

The code which I copied from the above SO post

```
def model = [:]
model['userInstance'] = userInstance
...
if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
    // set/lookup the error message
    model['errorMessage'] = message(code: 'some.error.message.you.lookup')
    // render the view
    render(view: 'theviewname', model: model)

    return
} else {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [LoginController.groovy](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity/LoginController.groovy) is part of the spring security core plugin. You can copy it to your application (remember to copy the folder structure so it matches the package). Once you have done that you can customize the controller.

So copy the controller to: `/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity/LoginController.groovy`

Comment: There's only a folder called `migration` inside `grails-app`. I am using grails 2.4.3.  Where can i find the source files ?